# Bash - reload profile or bashrc when switching to root

Tags: command-line, sudo, bashrc, .profile

Just moved over to ubuntu land from fedora (wanted try the budgie build).
I'm fed land I had a script (from Fedy - posted below.) that changed my prompt to red when I logged into the root shell with `sudo -s`, this doesn't appear to work in Ubuntu even though I have the following the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

---

Could one of you kind folks point out what is blocking or overwriting the export `PS1`?

Output of `cat /etc/profile.d/color_prompt.sh`:

```
# Colors in Terminal (Bash)
if [[ ! -z \$BASH ]]; then
    if [[ \$EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
        PS1="\[\033[33m\][\[\033[m\]\[\033[31m\]\u@\h\[\033[m\] \[\033[33m\]\W\[\033[m\]\[\033[33m\]]\[\033[m\] # "
    else
        PS1="\[\033[36m\][\[\033[m\]\[\033[34m\]\u@\h\[\033[m\] \[\033[32m\]\W\[\033[m\]\[\033[36m\]]\[\033[m\] \$ "
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Don't use `sudo -s` to login as root. Use `sudo -i` and get clean environment.

Comment: `-i`, and that might be a difference between Fedora & Ubuntu.

Comment: ahh, yeah that behaves differently in the redhat land. Thanks for pointing that out and for the article explaining the difference

Comment: I think you should use `==` in the test instead of `-eq`

Comment: @Zanna `==` is string comparison, `-eq` is integer comparison, which throws an error if one of the candidates can not be interpreted as a number. I think both ways are acceptable here.

Comment: the script is the one being taken from the fedy package (fixbashcolor.sh). The have a github I'm sure they'll love the comments. The script works fine though.